# dynamically deducing whether a csv/txt file has headers and skip if necessary

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, header-files

I am working on computer vision and often need to use codes like

```
with open(csv or txt file, "r") as input_file:
    headers = next(input_file)
    for row in input_file:
        image_name, x_min_norm, y_min_norm, x_max_norm, y_max_norm, class_idx = row.split(",")
```

However, I am not from computer science background and want to ask this naive question:

Question 1: Sometimes the csv/txt file given to me has headers like "img_name, xmin, ymin etc etc", and sometimes the files do not have headers. It is most often the case that I need to skip the headers to iterate through the rest of the data, but **what if** there are no headers in the files given, then it will skip my first row right? How do I fix this?

Question 2: when I want to row.split, I noticed in csv, sometimes it is row.split(", ") and sometimes its row.split(","). Is there a reason why?

Comment: Q1) there would only be a heurstic way Q2) one splits on `","` and the other on `", "`... note the space. In general, though, you should just use the `csv` module and don't parse using string methods yourself.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Sorry, would you mind explaining a bit more on heuristic way? I do not quite understand it

Comment: The headers likely have non-numeric characters only and the data probably has numeric characters. Can you check that way?

Comment: As is often the case with programming problems, you can make it easier by asking yourself the question: how would I do it myself? If you look at the .csv, how do you decide the first row is a header or not? What strict rules do you apply? Once you know, the only remaining problem is to code reusing the "header" line as the first data line in a nice and clean way.